# Task-Based Multithreading Library - Implemented using Fibers

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a library I wrote to enable task-based multithreading. It allows execution of task graphs with arbitrary dependencies. Dependencies are represented as atomic counters. Under the covers, the task graph is executed using fibers, which in turn, are run on a pool of worker threads (one thread per CPU core). This allows the scheduler to wait on dependencies without task chaining or context switches.

The code is inspired by the GDC presentation given by Christian Gyrling: ['Parallelizing the Naughty Dog Engine Using Fibers'](http://gdcvault.com/play/1022186/Parallelizing-the-Naughty-Dog-Engine)

The code for the library is all on github [here](https://github.com/RichieSams/FiberTaskingLib), however, I will give an overview of the major sections of the code below:

First an example of how the code is used:

```
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/task_scheduler.h"


struct NumberSubset {
    uint64 start;
    uint64 end;

    uint64 total;
};


FTL_TASK_ENTRY_POINT(AddNumberSubset) {
    NumberSubset *subset = reinterpret_cast<NumberSubset *>(arg);

    subset->total = 0;

    while (subset->start != subset->end) {
        subset->total += subset->start;
        ++subset->start;
    }

    subset->total += subset->end;
}


/**
 * Calculates the value of a triangle number by dividing the additions up into tasks
 *
 * A triangle number is defined as:
 *         Tn = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
 *
 * The code is checked against the numerical solution which is:
 *         Tn = n * (n + 1) / 2
 */
FTL_TASK_ENTRY_POINT(MainTask) {
    // Define the constants to test
    const uint64 triangleNum = 47593243ull;
    const uint64 numAdditionsPerTask = 10000ull;
    const uint64 numTasks = (triangleNum + numAdditionsPerTask - 1ull) / numAdditionsPerTask;

    // Create the tasks
    FiberTaskingLib::Task *tasks = new FiberTaskingLib::Task[numTasks];
    NumberSubset *subsets = new NumberSubset[numTasks];
    uint64 nextNumber = 1ull;

    for (uint64 i = 0ull; i < numTasks; ++i) {
        NumberSubset *subset = &subsets[i];

        subset->start = nextNumber;
        subset->end = nextNumber + numAdditionsPerTask - 1ull;
        if (subset->end > triangleNum) {
            subset->end = triangleNum;
        }

        tasks[i] = {AddNumberSubset, subset};

        nextNumber = subset->end + 1;
    }

    // Schedule the tasks and wait for them to complete
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> counter = taskScheduler->AddTasks(numTasks, tasks);
    delete[] tasks;

    taskScheduler->WaitForCounter(counter, 0);


    // Add the results
    uint64 result = 0ull;
    for (uint64 i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i) {
        result += subsets[i].total;
    }

    // Test
    assert(triangleNum * (triangleNum + 1ull) / 2ull == result);

    // Cleanup
    delete[] subsets;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    FiberTaskingLib::TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    taskScheduler.Run(25, MainTask);

    return 0;
}
```

## General Architecture of the TaskScheduler

**Task Queue** - An MPMC lockless queue for holding the tasks that are waiting to be executed. The queue is internally implemented as per-thread SPMC lockless queues, that can steal from each other.

**Fiber Pool** - A pool of 'free' fibers that can be used for switching to new tasks while the current task is waiting on a dependency. Fibers execute the tasks. Internally, the pool is implemented with two flat arrays. One array stores the fibers, the other stores atomic bools, which signal which fibers are in use.

**Worker Threads** - 1 per logical CPU core. These run the fibers.

**Waiting Tasks** - A list of the tasks that are waiting for a dependency to be fulfilled. Dependencies are represented with atomic counters. Internally, this is implemented with two flat arrays. One array stores the dependency data (fiber pointer, counter, expected value), and the other stores an atomic bool, which acts as a signal that the dependency is still waiting to be fulfilled.

The TaskScheduler class is defined in task_scheduler.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "fiber_tasking_lib/typedefs.h"
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/thread_abstraction.h"
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/fiber.h"
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/task.h"
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/wait_free_queue.h"

#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <memory>


namespace FiberTaskingLib {

/**
 * A class that enables task-based multithreading.
 *
 * Underneath the covers, it uses fibers to allow cores to work on other tasks
 * when the current task is waiting on a synchronization atomic
 */
class TaskScheduler {
public:
    TaskScheduler();
    ~TaskScheduler();

private:
    enum {
        FTL_INVALID_INDEX = UINT_MAX
    };

    std::size_t m_numThreads;
    std::vector<ThreadType> m_threads;    

    std::size_t m_fiberPoolSize;
    /* The backing storage for the fiber pool */
    Fiber *m_fibers;
    /**
     * An array of atomics, which signify if a fiber is available to be used. The indices of m_waitingFibers
     * correspond 1 to 1 with m_fibers. So, if m_freeFibers[i] == true, then m_fibers[i] can be used.
     * Each atomic acts as a lock to ensure that threads do not try to use the same fiber at the same time
     */
    std::atomic<bool> *m_freeFibers;
    /**
      * An array of atomic, which signify if a fiber is waiting for a counter. The indices of m_waitingFibers
      * correspond 1 to 1 with m_fibers. So, if m_waitingFibers[i] == true, then m_fibers[i] is waiting for a counter
      */
    std::atomic<bool> *m_waitingFibers;

    /**
     * Holds a Counter that is being waited on. Specifically, until Counter == TargetValue
     */
    struct WaitingBundle {
        std::atomic_uint *Counter;
        uint TargetValue;
    };
    /**
      * An array of WaitingBundles, which correspond 1 to 1 with m_waitingFibers. If m_waitingFiber[i] == true,
      * m_waitingBundles[i] will contain the data for the waiting fiber in m_fibers[i].
      */
    std::vector<WaitingBundle> m_waitingBundles;

    std::atomic_bool m_quit;

    enum class FiberDestination {
        None = 0,
        ToPool = 1,
        ToWaiting = 2,
    };

    /**
    * Holds a task that is ready to to be executed by the worker threads
    * Counter is the counter for the task(group). It will be decremented when the task completes
    */
    struct TaskBundle {
        Task TaskToExecute;
        std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> Counter;
    };

    struct ThreadLocalStorage {
        ThreadLocalStorage()
            : ThreadFiber(),
              CurrentFiberIndex(FTL_INVALID_INDEX),
              OldFiberIndex(FTL_INVALID_INDEX),
              OldFiberDestination(FiberDestination::None),
              TaskQueue(),
              LastSuccessfulSteal(1) {
        }

        /**
        * Boost fibers require that fibers created from threads finish on the same thread where they started
        *
        * To accommodate this, we have save the initial fibers created in each thread, and immediately switch
        * out of them into the general fiber pool. Once the 'mainTask' has finished, we signal all the threads to
        * start quitting. When the receive the signal, they switch back to the ThreadFiber, allowing it to 
        * safely clean up.
        */
        Fiber ThreadFiber;
        /* The index of the current fiber in m_fibers */
        std::size_t CurrentFiberIndex;
        /* The index of the previously executed fiber in m_fibers */
        std::size_t OldFiberIndex;
        /* Where OldFiber should be stored when we call CleanUpPoolAndWaiting() */
        FiberDestination OldFiberDestination;
        /* The queue of waiting tasks */
        WaitFreeQueue<TaskBundle> TaskQueue;
        /* The last queue that we successfully stole from. This is an offset index from the current thread index */
        std::size_t LastSuccessfulSteal;
    };
    /**
     * c++ Thread Local Storage is, by definition, static/global. This poses some problems, such as multiple TaskScheduler
     * instances. In addition, with Boost::Context, we have no way of telling the compiler to disable TLS optimizations, so we
     * have to fake TLS anyhow. 
     *
     * During initialization of the TaskScheduler, we create one ThreadLocalStorage instance per thread. Threads index into
     * their storage using m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()]
     */
    ThreadLocalStorage *m_tls;


public:
    /**
     * Initializes the TaskScheduler and then starts executing 'mainTask'
     *
     * NOTE: Run will "block" until 'mainTask' returns. However, it doesn't block in the traditional sense; 'mainTask' is created as a Fiber.
     * Therefore, the current thread will save it's current state, and then switch execution to the the 'mainTask' fiber. When 'mainTask'
     * finishes, the thread will switch back to the saved state, and Run() will return.
     *
     * @param fiberPoolSize     The size of the fiber pool. The fiber pool is used to run new tasks when the current task is waiting on a counter
     * @param mainTask          The main task to run
     * @param mainTaskArg       The argument to pass to 'mainTask'
     * @param threadPoolSize    The size of the thread pool to run. 0 corresponds to NumHarewareThreads()
     */
    void Run(uint fiberPoolSize, TaskFunction mainTask, void *mainTaskArg = nullptr, uint threadPoolSize = 0);

    /**
     * Adds a task to the internal queue.
     *
     * @param task    The task to queue
     * @return        An atomic counter corresponding to this task. Initially it will equal 1. When the task completes, it will be decremented.
     */
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> AddTask(Task task);
    /**
     * Adds a group of tasks to the internal queue
     *
     * @param numTasks    The number of tasks
     * @param tasks       The tasks to queue
     * @return            An atomic counter corresponding to the task group as a whole. Initially it will equal numTasks. When each task completes, it will be decremented.
     */
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> AddTasks(uint numTasks, Task *tasks);

    /**
     * Yields execution to another task until counter == value
     *
     * @param counter    The counter to check
     * @param value      The value to wait for
     */
    void WaitForCounter(std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> &counter, uint value);

private:
    /**
     * Gets the 0-based index of the current thread
     * This is useful for m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()]
     *
     * @return    The index of the current thread
     */
    std::size_t GetCurrentThreadIndex();
    /**
     * Pops the next task off the queue into nextTask. If there are no tasks in the
     * the queue, it will return false.
     *
     * @param nextTask    If the queue is not empty, will be filled with the next task
     * @return            True: Successfully popped a task out of the queue
     */
    bool GetNextTask(TaskBundle *nextTask);
    /**
     * Gets the index of the next available fiber in the pool
     *
     * @return    The index of the next available fiber in the pool
     */
    std::size_t GetNextFreeFiberIndex();
    /**
     * If necessary, moves the old fiber to the fiber pool or the waiting list
     * The old fiber is the last fiber to run on the thread before the current fiber
     */
    void CleanUpOldFiber();

    /**
     * The threadProc function for all worker threads
     *
     * @param arg    An instance of ThreadStartArgs
     * @return       The return status of the thread
     */
    static FTL_THREAD_FUNC_DECL ThreadStart(void *arg);
    /**
    * The fiberProc function that wraps the main fiber procedure given by the user
    *
    * @param arg    An instance of TaskScheduler
    */
    static void MainFiberStart(void *arg);
    /**
     * The fiberProc function for all fibers in the fiber pool
     *
     * @param arg    An instance of TaskScheduler
     */
    static void FiberStart(void *arg);
};

} // End of namespace FiberTaskingLib
```

Fiber are low-level structures, that enable fast switching between execution contexts. They use assembly to save out registers and then switch the stack pointer and execution pointer. Fiber is defined and implemented in fiber.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "fiber_tasking_lib/config.h"

#include <boost_context/fcontext.h>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

#if defined(FTL_VALGRIND)
    #include <valgrind/valgrind.h>
#endif

#if defined(FTL_FIBER_STACK_GUARD_PAGES)
    #if defined(FTL_OS_LINUX) || defined(FTL_OS_MAC) || defined(FTL_iOS)
        #include <sys/mman.h>
        #include <unistd.h>
    #elif defined(FTL_OS_WINDOWS)
        #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
        #include <Windows.h>
    #endif
#endif


namespace FiberTaskingLib {

#if defined(FTL_VALGRIND)
    #define FTL_VALGRIND_ID uint m_stackId

    #define FTL_VALGRIND_REGISTER(s, e) \
        m_stackId = VALGRIND_STACK_REGISTER(s, e)

    #define SEW_VALGRIND_DEREGISTER() VALGRIND_STACK_DEREGISTER(m_stackId)
#else
    #define FTL_VALGRIND_ID
    #define FTL_VALGRIND_REGISTER(s, e)
    #define FTL_VALGRIND_DEREGISTER()
#endif


inline void MemoryGuard(void *memory, size_t bytes);
inline void MemoryGuardRelease(void *memory, size_t bytes);
inline std::size_t SystemPageSize();
inline void *AlignedAlloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment);
inline void AlignedFree(void *block);
inline std::size_t RoundUp(std::size_t numToRound, std::size_t multiple);

typedef void (*FiberStartRoutine)(void *arg);


class Fiber {
public:
    /**
     * Default constructor
     * Nothing is allocated. This can be used as a thread fiber.
     */
    Fiber()
        : m_stack(nullptr),
          m_systemPageSize(0),
          m_stackSize(0),
          m_context(nullptr),
          m_arg(0) {
    }
    /**
     * Allocates a stack and sets it up to start executing 'startRoutine' when first switched to
     *
     * @param stackSize        The stack size for the fiber. If guard pages are being used, this will be rounded up to the next multiple of the system page size
     * @param startRoutine     The function to run when the fiber first starts
     * @param arg              The argument to pass to 'startRoutine'
     */
    Fiber(std::size_t stackSize, FiberStartRoutine startRoutine, void *arg)
            : m_arg(arg) {
        #if defined(FTL_FIBER_STACK_GUARD_PAGES)
            m_systemPageSize = SystemPageSize();
        #else
            m_systemPageSize = 0;
        #endif

        m_stackSize = RoundUp(stackSize, m_systemPageSize);
        // We add a guard page both the top and the bottom of the stack
        m_stack = AlignedAlloc(m_systemPageSize + m_stackSize + m_systemPageSize, m_systemPageSize);
        m_context = boost_context::make_fcontext(static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_systemPageSize + stackSize, stackSize, startRoutine);

        FTL_VALGRIND_REGISTER(static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_systemPageSize + stackSize, static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_systemPageSize);
        #if defined(FTL_FIBER_STACK_GUARD_PAGES)
            MemoryGuard(static_cast<char *>(m_stack), m_systemPageSize);
            MemoryGuard(static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_systemPageSize + stackSize, m_systemPageSize);
        #endif
    }

    /**
     * Deleted copy constructor
     * It makes no sense to copy a stack and its corresponding context. Therefore, we explicitly forbid it.
     */
    Fiber(const Fiber &other) = delete;
    /**
     * Move constructor
     * This does a swap() of all the member variables
     *
     * @param other
     *
     * @return
     */
    Fiber(Fiber &&other)
            : Fiber() {
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    /**
     * Move assignment operator
     * This does a swap() of all the member variables
     *
     * @param other    The fiber to move
     */
    Fiber &operator=(Fiber &&other) {
        swap(*this, other);

        return *this;
    }
    ~Fiber() {
        if (m_stack != nullptr) {
            if (m_systemPageSize != 0) {
                MemoryGuardRelease(static_cast<char *>(m_stack), m_systemPageSize);
                MemoryGuardRelease(static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_systemPageSize + m_stackSize, m_systemPageSize);
            }
            FTL_VALGRIND_DEREGISTER();

            AlignedFree(m_stack);
        }
    }

private:
    void *m_stack;
    std::size_t m_systemPageSize;
    std::size_t m_stackSize;
    boost_context::fcontext_t m_context;
    void *m_arg;
    FTL_VALGRIND_ID;

public:
    /**
     * Saves the current stack context and then switches to the given fiber
     * Execution will resume here once another fiber switches to this fiber
     *
     * @param fiber    The fiber to switch to
     */
    void SwitchToFiber(Fiber *fiber) {
        boost_context::jump_fcontext(&m_context, fiber->m_context, fiber->m_arg);
    }
    /**
     * Re-initializes the stack with a new startRoutine and arg
     *
     * NOTE: This can NOT be called on a fiber that has m_stack == nullptr || m_stackSize == 0
     *       AKA, a default constructed fiber.
     *
     * @param startRoutine    The function to run when the fiber is next switched to
     * @param arg             The arg for 'startRoutine'
     *
     * @return
     */
    void Reset(FiberStartRoutine startRoutine, void *arg) {
        m_context = boost_context::make_fcontext(static_cast<char *>(m_stack) + m_stackSize, m_stackSize, startRoutine);
        m_arg = arg;
    }

private:
    /**
    * Helper function for the move operators
    * Swaps all the member variables
    *
    * @param first     The first fiber
    * @param second    The second fiber
    */
    void swap(Fiber &first, Fiber &second) {
        using std::swap;

        swap(first.m_stack, second.m_stack);
        swap(first.m_systemPageSize, second.m_systemPageSize);
        swap(first.m_stackSize, second.m_stackSize);
        swap(first.m_context, second.m_context);
        swap(first.m_arg, second.m_arg);
    }
};

#if defined(FTL_FIBER_STACK_GUARD_PAGES)
    #if defined(FTL_OS_LINUX) || defined(FTL_OS_MAC) || defined(FTL_iOS)
        inline void MemoryGuard(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
            int result = mprotect(memory, bytes, PROT_NONE);
            if(result) {
                perror("mprotect failed with error:");
                assert(!result);
            }
        }

        inline void MemoryGuardRelease(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
            int result = mprotect(memory, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
            if(result) {
                perror("mprotect failed with error:");
                assert(!result);
            }
        }

        inline std::size_t SystemPageSize() {
            int pageSize = getpagesize();
            return pageSize;
        }

        inline void *AlignedAlloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment) {
            void *returnPtr;
            posix_memalign(&returnPtr, alignment, size);

            return returnPtr;
        }

        inline void AlignedFree(void *block) {
            free(block);
        }
    #elif defined(FTL_OS_WINDOWS)
        inline void MemoryGuard(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
            DWORD ignored;

            BOOL result = VirtualProtect(memory, bytes, PAGE_NOACCESS, &ignored);
            assert(result);
        }

        inline void MemoryGuardRelease(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
            DWORD ignored;

            BOOL result = VirtualProtect(memory, bytes, PAGE_READWRITE, &ignored);
            assert(result);
        }

        inline std::size_t SystemPageSize() {
            SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
            GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
            return sysInfo.dwPageSize;
        }

        inline void *AlignedAlloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment) {
            return _aligned_malloc(size, alignment);
        }

        inline void AlignedFree(void *block) {
            _aligned_free(block);
        }
    #else
        #error "Need a way to protect memory for this platform".
    #endif
#else
    inline void MemoryGuard(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
        (void)memory;
        (void)bytes;
    }

    inline void MemoryGuardRelease(void *memory, size_t bytes) {
        (void)memory;
        (void)bytes;
    }

    inline std::size_t SystemPageSize() {
        return 0;
    }

    inline void *AlignedAlloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment) {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    inline void AlignedFree(void *block) {
        free(block);
    }
#endif

inline std::size_t RoundUp(std::size_t numToRound, std::size_t multiple) {
    if (multiple == 0) {
        return numToRound;
    }

    std::size_t remainder = numToRound % multiple;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return numToRound;

    return numToRound + multiple - remainder;
}

} // End of namespace FiberTaskingLib
```

The main workings of the code is in the implementation of TaskScheduler in task_scheduler.cpp:

```
#include "fiber_tasking_lib/task_scheduler.h"


namespace FiberTaskingLib {

TaskScheduler::TaskScheduler()
    : m_numThreads(0),
      m_fiberPoolSize(0), 
      m_fibers(nullptr), 
      m_freeFibers(nullptr), 
      m_waitingFibers(nullptr),
      m_tls(nullptr) {
}

TaskScheduler::~TaskScheduler() {
    delete[] m_fibers;
    delete[] m_freeFibers;
    delete[] m_waitingFibers;
    delete[] m_tls;
}

void TaskScheduler::Run(uint fiberPoolSize, TaskFunction mainTask, void *mainTaskArg, uint threadPoolSize) {
    // Create and populate the fiber pool
    m_fiberPoolSize = fiberPoolSize;
    m_fibers = new Fiber[fiberPoolSize];
    m_freeFibers = new std::atomic<bool>[fiberPoolSize];
    m_waitingFibers = new std::atomic<bool>[fiberPoolSize];

    for (uint i = 0; i < fiberPoolSize; ++i) {
        m_fibers[i] = std::move(Fiber(512000, FiberStart, this));
        m_freeFibers[i].store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        m_waitingFibers[i].store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }
    m_waitingBundles.resize(fiberPoolSize);

    if (threadPoolSize == 0) {
        // 1 thread for each logical processor
        m_numThreads = GetNumHardwareThreads();
    } else {
        m_numThreads = threadPoolSize;
    }

    // Initialize all the things
    m_quit.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    m_threads.resize(m_numThreads);
    m_tls = new ThreadLocalStorage[m_numThreads];

    // Set the properties for the current thread
    SetCurrentThreadAffinity(1);
    m_threads[0] = GetCurrentThread();

    // Create the remaining threads
    for (uint i = 1; i < m_numThreads; ++i) {
        ThreadStartArgs *threadArgs = new ThreadStartArgs();
        threadArgs->taskScheduler = this;
        threadArgs->threadIndex = i;

        if (!CreateThread(524288, ThreadStart, threadArgs, i, &m_threads[i])) {
            printf("Error: Failed to create all the worker threads");
            return;
        }
    }


    // Start the main task

    // Get a free fiber
    std::size_t freeFiberIndex = GetNextFreeFiberIndex();
    Fiber *freeFiber = &m_fibers[freeFiberIndex];

    // Repurpose it as the main task fiber and switch to it
    MainFiberStartArgs mainFiberArgs;
    mainFiberArgs.taskScheduler = this;
    mainFiberArgs.MainTask = mainTask;
    mainFiberArgs.Arg = mainTaskArg;

    freeFiber->Reset(MainFiberStart, &mainFiberArgs);
    m_tls[0].CurrentFiberIndex = freeFiberIndex;
    m_tls[0].ThreadFiber.SwitchToFiber(freeFiber);


    // And we're back
    // Wait for the worker threads to finish
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < m_numThreads; ++i) {
        JoinThread(m_threads[i]);
    }

    return;
}

std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> TaskScheduler::AddTask(Task task) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> counter(new std::atomic_uint());
    counter->store(1);

    TaskBundle bundle = {task, counter};
    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()];
    tls.TaskQueue.Push(bundle);

    return counter;
}

std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> TaskScheduler::AddTasks(uint numTasks, Task *tasks) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> counter(new std::atomic_uint());
    counter->store(numTasks);

    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()];
    for (uint i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i) {
        TaskBundle bundle = {tasks[i], counter};
        tls.TaskQueue.Push(bundle);
    }

    return counter;
}

std::size_t TaskScheduler::GetCurrentThreadIndex() {
    #if defined(FTL_WIN32_THREADS)
        DWORD threadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i) {
            if (m_threads[i].Id == threadId) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    #elif defined(FTL_POSIX_THREADS)
        pthread_t currentThread = pthread_self();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i) {
            if (pthread_equal(currentThread, m_threads[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    #endif

    return FTL_INVALID_INDEX;
}

bool TaskScheduler::GetNextTask(TaskBundle *nextTask) {
    std::size_t currentThreadIndex = GetCurrentThreadIndex();
    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = m_tls[currentThreadIndex];

    // Try to pop from our own queue
    if (tls.TaskQueue.Pop(nextTask)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Ours is empty, try to steal from the others'
    std::size_t threadIndex = tls.LastSuccessfulSteal;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_numThreads; ++i) {
        const std::size_t threadIndexToStealFrom = (threadIndex + i) % m_numThreads;
        if (threadIndexToStealFrom == currentThreadIndex) {
            continue;
        }
        ThreadLocalStorage &otherTLS = m_tls[threadIndexToStealFrom];
        if (otherTLS.TaskQueue.Steal(nextTask)) {
            tls.LastSuccessfulSteal = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

std::size_t TaskScheduler::GetNextFreeFiberIndex() {
    for (uint j = 0; ; ++j) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_fiberPoolSize; ++i) {
            // Double lock
            if (!m_freeFibers[i].load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!m_freeFibers[i].load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                continue;
            }

            bool expected = true;
            if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&m_freeFibers[i], &expected, false, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        if (j > 10) {
            printf("No free fibers in the pool. Possible deadlock");
        }
    }
}

void TaskScheduler::CleanUpOldFiber() {
    // Clean up from the last Fiber to run on this thread
    //
    // Explanation:
    // When switching between fibers, there's the innate problem of tracking the fibers.
    // For example, let's say we discover a waiting fiber that's ready. We need to put the currently 
    // running fiber back into the fiber pool, and then switch to the waiting fiber. However, we can't 
    // just do the equivalent of:
    //     m_fibers.Push(currentFiber)
    //     currentFiber.SwitchToFiber(waitingFiber)
    // In the time between us adding the current fiber to the fiber pool and switching to the waiting fiber, another
    // thread could come along and pop the current fiber from the fiber pool and try to run it.
    // This leads to stack corruption and/or other undefined behavior. 
    //
    // In the previous implementation of TaskScheduler, we used helper fibers to do this work for us.
    // AKA, we stored currentFiber and waitingFiber in TLS, and then switched to the helper fiber. The
    // helper fiber then did:
    //     m_fibers.Push(currentFiber)
    //     helperFiber.SwitchToFiber(waitingFiber)
    // If we have 1 helper fiber per thread, we can guarantee that currentFiber is free to be executed by any thread 
    // once it is added back to the fiber pool
    //
    // This solution works well, however, we actually don't need the helper fibers
    // The code structure guarantees that between any two fiber switches, the code will always end up in WaitForCounter or FibeStart.
    // Therefore, instead of using a helper fiber and immediately pushing the fiber to the fiber pool or waiting list,
    // we defer the push until the next fiber gets to one of those two places
    // 
    // Proof:
    // There are only two places where we switch fibers:
    // 1. When we're waiting for a counter, we pull a new fiber from the fiber pool and switch to it.
    // 2. When we found a counter that's ready, we put the current fiber back in the fiber pool, and switch to the waiting fiber.
    //
    // Case 1:
    // A fiber from the pool will always either be completely new or just come back from switching to a waiting fiber
    // The while and the if/else in FiberStart will guarantee the code will call CleanUpOldFiber() before executing any other fiber. 
    // QED
    // 
    // Case 2:
    // A waiting fiber can do two things:
    //    a. Finish the task and return
    //    b. Wait on another counter
    // In case a, the while loop and if/else will again guarantee the code will call CleanUpOldFiber() before executing any other fiber.
    // In case b, WaitOnCounter will directly call CleanUpOldFiber(). Any further code is just a recursion.
    // QED

    // In this specific implementation, the fiber pool and waiting list are flat arrays signaled by atomics
    // So in order to "Push" the fiber to the fiber pool or waiting list, we just set their corresponding atomics to true
    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()];
    switch (tls.OldFiberDestination) {
    case FiberDestination::ToPool:
        m_freeFibers[tls.OldFiberIndex].store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        tls.OldFiberDestination = FiberDestination::None;
        tls.OldFiberIndex = FTL_INVALID_INDEX;
        break;
    case FiberDestination::ToWaiting:
        m_waitingFibers[tls.OldFiberIndex].store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        tls.OldFiberDestination = FiberDestination::None;
        tls.OldFiberIndex = FTL_INVALID_INDEX;
        break;
    case FiberDestination::None:
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void TaskScheduler::WaitForCounter(std::shared_ptr<std::atomic_uint> &counter, uint value) {
    // Fast out
    if (counter->load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == value) {
        return;
    }

    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = m_tls[GetCurrentThreadIndex()];

    // Fill in the WaitingBundle data
    WaitingBundle &bundle = m_waitingBundles[tls.CurrentFiberIndex];
    bundle.Counter = counter.get();
    bundle.TargetValue = value;

    // Get a free fiber
    std::size_t freeFiberIndex = GetNextFreeFiberIndex();

    // Clean up the old fiber
    CleanUpOldFiber();

    // Fill in tls
    tls.OldFiberIndex = tls.CurrentFiberIndex;
    tls.CurrentFiberIndex = freeFiberIndex;
    tls.OldFiberDestination = FiberDestination::ToWaiting;

    // Switch
    m_fibers[tls.OldFiberIndex].SwitchToFiber(&m_fibers[freeFiberIndex]);

    // And we're back
}

} // End of namespace FiberTaskingLib
```

The worker threads run ThreadStart()

```
struct ThreadStartArgs {
    TaskScheduler *taskScheduler;
    uint threadIndex;
};

FTL_THREAD_FUNC_RETURN_TYPE TaskScheduler::ThreadStart(void *arg) {
    ThreadStartArgs *threadArgs = reinterpret_cast<ThreadStartArgs *>(arg);
    TaskScheduler *taskScheduler = threadArgs->taskScheduler;
    uint index = threadArgs->threadIndex;

    // Clean up
    delete threadArgs;


    // Get a free fiber to switch to
    std::size_t freeFiberIndex = taskScheduler->GetNextFreeFiberIndex();

    // Initialize tls
    taskScheduler->m_tls[index].CurrentFiberIndex = freeFiberIndex;
    // Switch
    taskScheduler->m_tls[index].ThreadFiber.SwitchToFiber(&taskScheduler->m_fibers[freeFiberIndex]);


    // And we've returned

    // Cleanup and shutdown
    EndCurrentThread();
    FTL_THREAD_FUNC_END;
}

struct MainFiberStartArgs {
    TaskFunction MainTask;
    void *Arg;
    TaskScheduler *taskScheduler;
};
```

And the fibers in the fiber pool all run FiberStart():

```
void TaskScheduler::FiberStart(void *arg) {
    TaskScheduler *taskScheduler = reinterpret_cast<TaskScheduler *>(arg);

    while (!taskScheduler->m_quit.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        // Clean up from the last fiber to run on this thread
        taskScheduler->CleanUpOldFiber();

        // Check if any of the waiting tasks are ready
        std::size_t waitingFiberIndex = FTL_INVALID_INDEX;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < taskScheduler->m_fiberPoolSize; ++i) {
            // Double lock
            if (!taskScheduler->m_waitingFibers[i].load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!taskScheduler->m_waitingFibers[i].load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Found a waiting fiber
            // Test if it's ready
            WaitingBundle *bundle = &taskScheduler->m_waitingBundles[i];
            if (bundle->Counter->load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != bundle->TargetValue) {
                continue;
            }

            bool expected = true;
            if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&taskScheduler->m_waitingFibers[i], &expected, false, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
                waitingFiberIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (waitingFiberIndex != FTL_INVALID_INDEX) {
            // Found a waiting task that is ready to continue
            ThreadLocalStorage &tls = taskScheduler->m_tls[taskScheduler->GetCurrentThreadIndex()];

            tls.OldFiberIndex = tls.CurrentFiberIndex;
            tls.CurrentFiberIndex = waitingFiberIndex;
            tls.OldFiberDestination = FiberDestination::ToPool;

            // Switch
            taskScheduler->m_fibers[tls.OldFiberIndex].SwitchToFiber(&taskScheduler->m_fibers[tls.CurrentFiberIndex]);

            // And we're back
        } else {
            // Get a new task from the queue, and execute it
            TaskBundle nextTask;
            if (!taskScheduler->GetNextTask(&nextTask)) {
                // Spin
            } else {
                nextTask.TaskToExecute.Function(taskScheduler, nextTask.TaskToExecute.ArgData);
                nextTask.Counter->fetch_sub(1);
            }
        }
    }


    // Start the quit sequence

    // Switch to the thread fibers
    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = taskScheduler->m_tls[taskScheduler->GetCurrentThreadIndex()];
    taskScheduler->m_fibers[tls.CurrentFiberIndex].SwitchToFiber(&tls.ThreadFiber);


    // We should never get here
    printf("Error: FiberStart should never return");
}
```

Lastly, when the user calls TaskScheduler::Run(), we switch to a fiber that runs MainFiberStart(). This makes cleanup at the end a bit easier.

```
void TaskScheduler::MainFiberStart(void *arg) {
    MainFiberStartArgs *mainFiberArgs = reinterpret_cast<MainFiberStartArgs *>(arg);
    TaskScheduler *taskScheduler = mainFiberArgs->taskScheduler;

    // Call the main task procedure
    mainFiberArgs->MainTask(taskScheduler, mainFiberArgs->Arg);


    // Request that all the threads quit
    taskScheduler->m_quit.store(true, std::memory_order_release);

    // Switch to the thread fibers
    ThreadLocalStorage &tls = taskScheduler->m_tls[taskScheduler->GetCurrentThreadIndex()];
    taskScheduler->m_fibers[tls.CurrentFiberIndex].SwitchToFiber(&tls.ThreadFiber);


    // We should never get here
    printf("Error: FiberStart should never return");
}
```

## General explanation of the code flow

1. User calls TaskScheduler::Run()
2. The TaskScheduler creates the thread pool, the waiting task list, and the fiber pool
3. Then Run() switches to the MainFiber, and begins running the mainTask passed as an arg to Run()
4. The worker threads start running ThreadStart
5. The workers threads initialize their data, then switch to free fibers
6. In FiberStart, the code runs in a loop
7. First, we loop through the waiting tasks array of atomic bools, searching for any of them to be true (Aka, waiting for it's counter to be a specific value)
8. If we find one that's true, we check the counter vs the expected value
9. If the check is successful, we CAS the atomic bool, to see if we were the first thread to find this ready task
10. If we win the CAS, we store the pointer to the current fiber in per-thread storage, for later cleanup. Then we fiber switch to the ready task
11. If we fail the CAS, we keep looking for more ready tasks.
12. If there are none, then we look for a task to run from the task queue (TaskScheduler::GetNextTask() )
13. In GetNextTask, we first look at our own thread-specific task queue, to see if there are any tasks to execute.
14. If our queue is empty, we loop through the other threads, and try to steal a task from them.
15. If GetNextTasks returns a valid task, we execute it
16. After executing the task, or if we didn't find a task, we loop back to the start
17. When mainTask returns, MainFiber sets TaskScheduler::m_quit to true. This causes FiberStart to finish its loop.
18. All the fibers switch back to the threads.
19. MainFiber waits for all the threads to finish, then switches back to Run(), and returns to the user's calling code

---

Answer (score 4):

You copied code from **boost.context** which is licensed under **BOOST license**.
But because your 'fiber_tasking_lib' is licensed under **Apache 2.0** the copied code from Boost is **re-licensed** under Apache 2.0 - but this is not permitted.

Edit: Why not simply linking against boost.context?

Comment: I believe this would be a good comment, or even more, a flag.

Comment: @Incomputable I believe this is a perfectly valid point and a valid review of the code. Although a [link to the BOOST license](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html) wouldn't hurt, and a description for how to do it correctly.

Comment: The ASM files have the boost license referenced directly in the source. What is the proper way to identify the different licenses? An entry in the readme? An elaborated version of: "The main library is released under the Apache 2 license. However, the library uses code from other open source projects that have their own licenses. They are as follows:

 * Fiber ASM files - Boost License
 * GTest - New BSD License

Comment: Taken from the boost license page: "the Boost license is not "viral": if you distribute your own code along with some Boost code, the Boost license applies only to the Boost code (and modified versions thereof); you are free to license your own code under any terms you like."

Comment: To answer your edit: The boost code in FiberTaskingLib is an edited version of boost master. So linking will not work. Secondly, the boost::context API has changed 3 times over the course of its lifetime. Detecting and forcing a specific version of boost is not fun.

Comment: you can detect the boost version with BOOST_VERSION; context API can be selected with BOOST_EXECUTION_CONTEXT

Comment: The Boost community has discussed that some weeks ago (copying code from Boost and publish in a project with another license). The conclusion was that this is unfair and not legal. Note that even open source licenses might not be compatible (lawyer with a presentation regarding to mixing open source licenses and derivative work).

Comment: @xlrg As noted above, I have made no attempt to hide the license of the Boost code. In each of the source files, the first lines state that they are licensed under the Boost license. So, I'm not following why this counts as "relicensing". In addition, I am not publishing the code as my own. I am merely re-distributing the modified code. This is explicitly allowed under the Boost license. However, that all said, can you please elaborate *how* I should notate / distribute the code so that these licensing questions don't arise again in the future.

Comment: @RichieSams, you made the code now part of your library which is licensed under Apache 2.0. Keep the boost code in the third_party folder as you did before. - att least I've concerns to mix Apache and Boost license in one project.

Comment: I've reverted the commit that moved the asm into the main library. In addition, I have added more documentation to better identify the different licenses and what code they pertain to. See https://github.com/RichieSams/FiberTaskingLib/compare/4e2ec744debdcf772cf8f7e9246f5bdaf8d9f239...cfeedb07eb89d406f07381d766c4e067563fe57d